# database is locked (code 5) after using ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-room, android-syncadapter

I'm using Room Persistence as a database in my project.

For using Android SyncAdapter, I have to use ContentProvider to access the database.

Now after a few weeks, I see `database is locked (code 5)` in Firebase Crashlytics was happened a lot exactly where ContentProvider want to access/update into the database via Room.

UPDATE 1:

Some details:

- I'm using SyncAdapter with AbstractAccountAuthenticator for sync some data with the server.
- ContentProvider uses Room's Dao classes for CRUD operations.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Why are you using a SyncAdapter at all? There's a lot better options for background syncing such as WorkManager.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Do SyncAdapter can replace completely with SyncAdapter?

Comment: if you just want to sync data with a server, yeah: WorkManager is going to give you a way better experience

Comment: @ianhanniballake even if I use SyncAdapter beside `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake also do using WorkManager solve the problem? How does this happen?